# render pdf in play 2.2.1 framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

Any hint how to render pdf in play framework 2.2.1? 
The pdf module mentioned in documentation is not supported anymore.
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0-M1/Modules
And I'm not sure if it's needed.

I just want to render a pdf from a directory. So, is there any way to do that? Thanks.

I suppose, something like this should be done.
Controller:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

public static Result showPDF(){

    File file = new java.io.File("E:\\Sample.pdf");

    return ok(start.render(file)).as("application/pdf");
}
```

View:

```
//I don't know how to declare here what is returned from the Controller    
//something like this, I suppose
<div>@routes.Application.showPDF()
```